# How to see the details which Ubuntu shows at the time of login anytime?

Tags: command-line, login, gnome-terminal

When I login to my ubuntu system, it show me this this message, How can I see it any time? I tried to run `. .bashrc` but it didn't worked.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.10 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-24-virtual x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Sat Jul 13 06:16:35 UTC 2013

  System load:  0.55              Processes:           96
  Usage of /:   8.1% of 68.74GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 55%               IP address for eth0: 198.xx.xxx.xxx
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for eth1: xxx.1x0.xx.xxx

  => There is 1 zombie process.

  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/

223 packages can be updated.
134 updates are security updates.

Last login: Mon Jul  8 17:47:05 2013
```

Comment: So sad that there is actually no standard command to just acomplish this, and that methods change so frequently that the accepted answer and its replacement have both already been obsoleted!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can show anytime when you wish this message - ***m**essage **o**f **t**he **d**ay* - using next command in terminal:

```
cat /etc/motd
```

or, better:

```
for i in /etc/update-motd.d/*; do if [ "$i" != "/etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot" ]; then $i; fi; done
```

If you want to see this message everytime when you open a terminal, just insert one of the above lines at the end of `~/.bashrc` file (you can open it with `gedit ~/.bashrc` command).

> The **/etc/motd** is a file on Unix-like systems that contains a "message of the day", used to send a common message to all users, in a more efficient manner than sending them all an e-mail message.

More about: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_(Unix)

Related: [How is /etc/motd updated?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105689/how-is-etc-motd-updated)

Comment: The same, but shorter discharging error messages (as from time to time the contents fo /etc/update-motd.d change):
for i in /etc/update-motd.d/*; do $i 2>/dev/null; done

Comment: You can no longer `cat /etc/motd`, unfortunately, as others have noted. And it has changed twice since that. (Why isn't there a standard command to do this? sigh)

Answer (score 64):

Looks like it changed. With Ubuntu 16.04 there is no `/etc/motd` but you can `cat /var/run/motd.dynamic` instead.

Comment: I had to use this method in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Note that `/var/run/motd.dynamic` is just a cached static output of the last time it was run, upon login.  To actually see live output again, you have to run the scripts that generate it, which are in `/etc/update-motd.d` (as of this writing, on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS)

Comment: As of Ubuntu 19.04, it is now `cat /var/run/motd.dynamic.new`

Answer (score 38):

As noted a few times, scripts under `/etc/update-motd.d` are what provide the typical output shown upon logging in; see `update-motd(5)`. But there's little or no need to reinvent the wheel, by scripting something yourself to run each script in turn so as to recreate the desired functionality. Use `run-parts(8)` instead, which is provided for just such a purpose:

```
sudo run-parts /etc/update-motd.d
```

This is akin to what the `pam_motd(8)` PAM module does, running as root, after user authentication and just before opening a user login shell.

Note that `run-parts` itself requires no special privileges; however, one or more of the `update-motd` scripts typically have needed them. So, unless you're in a root shell, don't leave off the `sudo` when you run this, or else you will likely see errors and stale system information displayed.

[2022-09-24: Self-edited for clarity. --RichieD]

Comment: This is the best answer as it a) updates the data b)runs only appropriate scripts c) prints the resulting output.

Answer (score 18):

Ubuntu runs this at login:

```
/usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo
```

You can simply run it through terminal using following command:

```
landscape-sysinfo
```

Comment: Interesting.  But that is only one part of the full motd.

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to refresh and display the motd, try:

```
run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/
```

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that this can be done without `sudo`.  Clearly it's done on login without `sudo`.  :)

Comment: @nonrectangular: When "done on login", the equivalent of the above command is run _as root_, before the system opens a user shell for you.  `run-parts` itself doesn't require root privileges; it's just a handy tool to run some scripts grouped into a named directory.  However the scripts therein may well require some privileges; typically `50-landscape-sysinfo` is such a case, pertinent to this question.  Hence my advice to run with `sudo` or in a root shell.  But sure, if you don't mind seeing error messages or stale system info, you needn't bother with that fussiness: nothing will break.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You have not yet enabled **hushed mode** as I see. If you enable hushed mode login, the answers in the previous solution's will not work.

You can see the [`motd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/update-motd.5.html) message in either `/var/run/motd.dynamic` and `/run/motd.dynamic` that was generated the last time a user has logged in **non-hushed mode**. Both the files point to the same inode which mean they are hard links.

The information is static once you login if you do not login in **hushed mode**. The file is not generated if you are the first user who does login to the system and if you have `.hushlogin` file. If you have a user who did not have the `.hushlogin` file, you will see the stale contents when you try to access that.

The best way I can think of is by creating a `.hushlogin` simply by doing `touch ~/.hushlogin`.

Edit you `.bashrc` file and add the contents as @Radu Rădeanu has pointed:

```
for i in /etc/update-motd.d/*; do if [ "$i" != "/etc/update-motd.d/98-fsck-at-reboot" ]; then $i; fi; done
```

So whenever you run `. .bashrc`, you will see new message instead of the static message.

Note: `.bashrc` is executed for all non-login interactive shells and hence you will see this messages when you open an interactive shell by typing `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like that output is generated by the scripts located in the folder `/etc/update-motd.d`;
If you go into that directory, you can run the individual scripts for the different bits of info; or you can look at the source of the scripts to see the commands it's actually running to get that information, which seem to change from release to release (using `cat`, or a text editor, such as `nano`, `pico`, `emacs`, `vim`, etc.).

Example:

```
$ ll /etc/update-motd.d/
total 44
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root 4096 Feb 25 21:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x 110 root root 4096 Feb 25 21:33 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1220 Oct 22  2015 00-header*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 1157 Jun 14  2016 10-help-text*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  334 Jan 12 14:30 51-cloudguest*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root   97 May 24  2016 90-updates-available*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  299 Jul 22  2016 91-release-upgrade*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  111 May 11  2017 97-overlayroot*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  142 May 24  2016 98-fsck-at-reboot*
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  144 May 24  2016 98-reboot-required*
-rwxrwxr-x   1 root root 1204 Jan 15 19:11 99-one-click*
```

This information is current as of this writing and Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is managed by PAM, via `/etc/pam.d/login`, look for `motd` (message of the day).

You can produce the static part of that message with `cat /etc/motd`.
I do not have the dynamic part that you show, so I cannot help with that.

Answer (score 2):

Aaron Wallentine's answer led me to my solution.
"Looks like that output is generated by the scripts located in the folder `/etc/update-motd.d`. If you go into that directory, you can run the individual scripts for the different bits of info."

Each of the scripts in the folder `/etc/update-motd.d` run, I believe, in order of the number they have in their names at login. As an example mine were:

```
10-header 30-sysinfo  32-site  35-motd  98-autoreboot-warn
```

You can run each separately to display their data. e.g.:

```
cd /etc/update-motd.d
sudo ./10-header  or  sudo ./30-sysinfo**
```

You could run them all together like this:

`sudo /etc/update-motd.d/10-header ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/30-sysinfo ; ...`
using the `;`(semi-colon) symbol to link commands.

but who wants to type all that out, i ended up turning that long linked command string into a shell script.

Change to the bin directory:

```
cd /bin
```

create a file, i called mine "clr" because im using it to clear my screen too, call yours whatever:

```
sudo touch clr
```

Make your script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x clr
```

I used nano to edit mine, use your favorite:

```
sudo nano clr
```

Then, add that long command string from before to your file, remember to use your motd files, not mine, as they will be different:

`clear ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/10-header ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/30-sysinfo ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/ ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/32-site ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/35-motd  ; sudo /etc/update-motd.d/98-autoreboot-warn`

Save it, and run it whenever to see your motd freshly updated, note I added  `clear ;` in mine, so when I type `clr` it will clear my screen and show updated stats.

I think that is all I got, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

You could run landscape-sysinfo for system information and

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available
```

for information about packets.

Comment: obviously this works only if you have landscape installed.  It is a commercial (not free) tool (for those that don't know about it).

Comment: I get: `find: ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Permission denied` and `mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/var/lib/update-notifier/tmp.XXXXXXXXXX’: Permission denied
`