# How do I bring back the initial 'stats page' (message of the day) after an upgrade to 14.04 server?

Tags: server

I've been using Ubuntu Server for quite a while, and I like seeing this when I log on over SSH:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 13.04 (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-35-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Mon Apr 21 02:06:46 UTC 2014

  System load:  0.0               Processes:           88
  Usage of /:   64.8% of 7.75GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 64%               IP address for eth0: xx.xx.xxx.xxx
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

  Use Juju to deploy your cloud instances and workloads:
    https://juju.ubuntu.com/#cloud-raring

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

*** /dev/xvda1 will be checked for errors at next reboot ***

Last login: Fri Apr 18 21:29:50 2014 from bla-bla-bla.foo.bar.net
ubuntu@ip-xx-yy-zzz-aaa:~$
```

After upgrading one of my servers to 14.04, though, I only see this:

```
$ ssh closet
Last login: Sun Apr 20 19:42:57 2014 from 192.168.0.7
me@server1:~$
```

I don't like this as much. How can I bring back the old welcome screen?

Comment: How did you upgrade? I've upgraded my personal dedicated server from 13.04 to 13.10 (note, as typed, you missed a release) and then 14.04 via the do-release-upgrade system. My system currently runs Trusty, and still displays the "summary" output. It's possible that a package migration changed this behavior, and knowing the interim packages might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I upgraded straight from 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS.)

Comment: Did you use apt-get dist-upgrade, or the do-release-upgrade tool?

Comment: I used `do-release-upgrade`.

Comment: @K.DarienFreeheart dist-upgrade doesn't upgrade distributions.

Comment: What is the output of `ls /etc | grep motd`?

Comment: @Seth it outputs `update-motd.d`.

Comment: @Undo There should also be a plaintext file called `motd`. Not there?

Comment: @Seth I don't see it - it's that single line, with `motd` colored in red.

Comment: Do you have `/var/run/motd`?

Comment: Yes I do, @Seth. It looks like it contains what I want when logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the information gathered in the comments, you don't have the `/etc/motd` file. Since this is just a symlink to `/var/run/motd` and you confirmed that you have that file just recreate the link with:

```
sudo ln -s /var/run/motd /etc/motd
```

Reboot the server.

---

Trivia:

- motd stands for "Message of the day". It contains the information you see when you boot the server.
- The scripts in the `/etc/update-motd.d` folder [update the motd on boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/105691/44179).

Answer (score 8):

The stats you see are provided by a script that uses the output of `landscape-sysinfo` in the `update-motd` building process. It appears to not be installed by default in 14.04 anymore.

Install `landscape-common` to have the stats re-inserted into the motd. (It might take 10 minutes for the cronjob to update the motd after installation).