# Available updates not shown when login to terminal Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, updates, ssh, login, motd

When I login to my server terminal over `ssh` I just see:

```
Using username "username".
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Authenticating with public key "mykey" from agent
Last login: Wed Oct 22 09:17:02 2014 from xxx.xxx.xxx.x
```

The login should normaly tell me something like this:

```
    Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-33-generic x86_64)
    * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
6 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.
```

Why is that, how an where should I change settings so that available updates are shown when logging to terminal shell?

This update notification was working OK but it just stopped a week ago or so. Maybe I did some stupid change that I am not aware of.

I hope someone can help me about this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Thats the message of the day (`motd`). Check if the file `/etc/motd` is existing and has content. When typing:

```
cat /etc/motd
```

...you should see the message like this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-58-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

115 packages can be updated.
115 updates are security updates.
```

Probably that file is empty in your case. The following packages need to be installed that the file is updated periodically:

```
base-files
update-notifier-common
```

You can force recreation of the file with this command:

```
run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/
```

**Edit:**

The [manpage of pam_motd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_motd.8.html) says that there is a flag called `noupdate` to prevent updateing the motd.  Edit the file `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. In the file edit the line:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
```

to:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/var/run/motd
```

Comment: well, there is no /etc/motd   =  cat /etc/motd
cat: /etc/motd: No such file or directory

Comment: @MarkoAmbrožič are the packages I mentioned installed? Have you tried the last command in my answer?

Comment: I have checked and all packages ate installed. I have tried comamnds: "run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/"  and "dpkg -S /etc/update-motd.d/*"  with no errors. I manualy created link /var/run/motd to /etc/motd (in /etc : motd -> /var/run/motd. But still no changes to generated motd.....

Comment: And the file `/var/run/motd` contains nothing? Also can you provide the output of `grep motd /etc/pam.d/*`?

Comment: I posted replay as an answer because as comment text was too long.

Comment: @MarkoAmbrožič sry you have to delete your answer. You can use http://pastebin.com/ for such things or better edit your question. But anyway I found the problem: I update my answer, one moment.

Comment: @MarkoAmbrožič see my edit

Comment: OK just a moment..., and I have deleted my answer as you recommend

Comment: I edited /etc/pam.d/sshd as you described but cat /etc/motd is stil empty after run-parts /etc/update-motd.d

Comment: You have to login again via ssh to regenerate the file

Comment: I did that of course. But it is still the same. http://pastebin.com/HaQRr5dk

Comment: And the file `/var/run/motd`?

Comment: cat /var/run/motd - still epty

Comment: I'm out of bullets. Maybe the permission and owner of the files are not corretly. Are scripts inside /etc/update-motd.d? And are they executable? Does that command give an ouput? `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` It's the script that checks the updates

Comment: Huh; scripts are in place, executable owner by root:root ; /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available - no output

Comment: and I see this: no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory which is samba memory leak as I can remember -To fix it, run pam-auth-update and make sure SMB password synchronization is deselected - I think the problem with update-notifier starts at that time...

Comment: The `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` command should produce the output. When there is no output you should debug that script.

Comment: and the end of the mentioned script is "/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable" it outputs: 0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates. But the script itself does not give me any output

Comment: try it with `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force` So it must execute that line.

Comment: It works with --force. Looking here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/105689/how-is-etc-motd-updated/105691#105691  - the "run-parts /etc/update-motd.d/ | sudo tee /etc/motd"  output is: Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-37-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.  But when I log out and login again the updates are not shown. Will see what will happen when I reboot the server....

Comment: What is the purpose of changing the `motd` option value in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` from `/run/motd.dynamic` to `/var/run/motd`? I was able to get my motd updating just by removing the `noupdate` option.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://oitibs.com/ubuntu-16-04-dynamic-motd/) solved the problem for me with no muss and no fuss on Ubuntu 16.04. Except the part about having to delete and recreate the /etc/update-motd.d directory; that seems to have been misguided.

But basically:

```
apt-get install lsb-release figlet update-motd
```

seems to have done it for me on 16.04