# Run TTY script every time I open a GUI terminal

Tags: command-line, permissions, login, tty, groups

When I log in to a TTY I get the following nice text:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS
Log-in: username
Password:
Last log-in date/time
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS

 * Documentation:
 * Management:
 * Support:

9 packages to update
4 updates are security updates
```

I would like the last 2 lines repeated every time I open a GUI terminal for all users in the `adm` group (but will settle for having the entire thing displayed each and every time I open a GUI Terminal for all users)

I tried the obvious:

```
fab-root@fab-ux-predator:~
$ cd /etc/update-motd.d/
fab-root@fab-ux-predator:/etc/update-motd.d
$ ./90-updates-available 
fab-root@fab-ux-predator:/etc/update-motd.d
$ cat /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
cat: /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available: Permission denied
fab-root@fab-ux-predator:/etc/update-motd.d
$
```

*What am I missing?*

P.S. Obviously I can `chmod o+r` the file, but how future-proof would that be?

Comment: Feature of *updates-available* creation by */usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit slow but it will generate the package/update information. Append this to the users `.bashrc` file:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable
```

Comment: Going to try both solutions tonight...  Upvoted both already.

Comment: Sorry for not coming back yet, but there haven't been any updateable packages yet...

Comment: @Fabby Thorough testing is a good thing. Haste is not very forgiving :-)

Comment: I tested, and on my machine with the OS running on an SSD with not too many packages installed, it runs<1sec.  **:-)** Looking good!

Comment: @Fabby There user will probably hardly notice the delay if it is preceded with a fortune.

Answer (score 2):

The entire output is in `/run/motd.dynamic`:

```
$ grep motd /etc/pam.d -R
/etc/pam.d/sshd:# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/sshd:# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/sshd:session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate
/etc/pam.d/login:# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/login:# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
/etc/pam.d/login:session    optional   pam_motd.so motd=/run/motd.dynamic
/etc/pam.d/login:session    optional   pam_motd.so noupdate
```

So, in your `.bashrc`, you could append:

```
[[ -r /run/motd.dynamic ]] && cat /run/motd.dynamic
```

Or:

```
[[ -r /run/motd.dynamic ]] && grep update /run/motd.dynamic
```

Comment: Does this file only get updated when someone logs in?

Comment: Seems so: https://askubuntu.com/q/105689/158442

Comment: ... so opening a new terminal will show stale information if no one has logged in recently :-(.

Comment: That's already better than what I currently have!  @StephenKitt

Comment: @StephenKitt Fabby can probably set up a cron job to force update the MOTD every day or so. The scripts generating the MOTD will add a noticeable delay to shell startup if run every time.

Comment: @muru yes, or perhaps better, as an `apt` hook...

Comment: Sorry for not coming back yet, but there haven't been any updateable packages yet...

Comment: @Fabby Meh. I've seen TTAs (time-to-accept) of more than 1.5 years. This is nothing.

Comment: Sorry Muru, but Stumblebee's solution worked better for me **:(**